# Qual è il significato di "priorato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Disse: – Sentili, come saltano e come bestemmiano. Per farli venire a pregar la madonna il parroco bisogna che li lasci sfogare. E loro per potersi sfogare bisogna che accendano i lumi alla madonna. Chi dei due frega l’altro? 
>         – Si fregano a turno, – dissi. 
>         – No no, – disse Nuto, – la vince il parroco. Chi è che paga l’illuminazione, i mortaretti, il **priorato** e la musica? E chi se la ride l’indomani della festa? Dannati, si rompono la schiena per quattro palmi di terra, e poi se li fanno mangiare.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "priorato" in questo brano? Quello che ho trovato nei dizionari che ho consultato non sembra avere senso nel contesto del testo. Si tratta di italiano regionale?

Comment: Nella mia terra esiste [questo vino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priorato_(vino)), ma non credo fosse conosciuto nel Piemonte del primo dopoguerra in cui si svolge la vicenda narrata nel romanzo.

Comment: Probabilmente al priorato si doveva comunque pagare una sorta di affitto per organizzare la festa in locali di proprietà della chiesa, insieme all’ illuminazione, i mortaretti e la musica. Il parroco con la, passami il termine, scusa di pregar la madonna faceva pagare ai contadini il costo della festa. Anche per i Cavalieri di Malta il priorato era l’organo preposto all’amministrazione dei possedimenti compresi in più commende, presieduto da un priore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La citazione della domanda appare appunto come esempio di uso del [vocabolo "priorato" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI14/GDLI_14_ocr_398.pdf). Secondo questo dizionario, il termine "priorato" viene usato nel testo della domanda per indicare il gruppo di persone che hanno il titolo di priore

> – Con riferimento a una confraternita laicale.

E riporta questo altro esempio letterario di uso di "priorato" con lo stesso significato:

> *Carducci*,  III-5-83:  Voi degnamente  lo eleggeste al priorato nella confraternita  della  Madre  dei  Dolori  (la  quale a quest’ora  sfavillando  tutta  di  un  riso  ha  raccolto  quell’a­nima  cara  sotto  il  suo  manto).

Alla voce "[priore](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI14/GDLI_14_ocr_399.pdf)" di questo stesso dizionario si trovano queste accezioni:

> – Capo  elettivo  di  una  confraternita  laicale. -  Anche:  nella  vecchia  organizzazione  parrocchia­
>   le,  ciascuno  dei  fedeli  laici  designati  periodica­
>   mente  a  collaborare  con  il  parroco  soprattutto  per 
>   le  esigenze  materiali  della  parrocchia.  -  Anche: 
>   promotore di una festa o sagra religiosa.

Quindi, l'interpretazione sarebbe che i contadini dovevano pagare ai promotori della festa in onore della Madonna, che probabilmente erano i capi di una confraternita laicale dedicata  alla Madonna.

Answer (score 1):

Probabilmente al priorato si doveva comunque pagare una sorta di affitto per organizzare la festa in locali di proprietà della chiesa, insieme all’ illuminazione, i mortaretti e la musica. Il parroco con la, passami il termine, scusa di pregar la madonna faceva pagare ai contadini il costo della festa.

Anche per i Cavalieri di Malta il [priorato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/priorato/) era l’organo preposto all’amministrazione dei possedimenti compresi in più commende, presieduto da un priore.

Comment: Si doveva pagare ai priori di che cosa? Non riesco a immaginarlo.

Comment: Mettiamola così: il parroco organizza la festa con tutte le spese connesse tra cui, presumo, una specie di affitto, tassa o comunque una cifra che va al priorato (non sono ferrato sull’argomento ma oggi dovrebbe chiamarsi diocesi). Coloro che vengono alla festa in onore della madonna accendono i lumi ed era (ed è) ancora oggi usanza inserire una moneta nell’urna posta sotto i candelieri. Il senso del passaggio è che alla fine il bilancio tra i costi sostenuti per la festa e le offerte era senz’altro a favore di queste ultime. Ecco perché alla fine rideva il parroco.

Comment: Priorato e diocesi sono termini non sostituibili. Il priore è il superiore di una comunità religiosa, che può anche essere una parrocchia collegiata, cioè con un collegio di canonici. Per estensione, priore può anche essere il parroco dove non ci siano canonici. La diocesi è il territorio su cui ha giurisdizione un vescovo. Vedrei bene, in questo caso, *priorato* come avente un suffisso che indica un tributo.

Comment: @egreg: "Avente un suffisso che indica un tributo": non capisco cosa vuoi dire con questo.

Answer (score 1):

Forse in senso meno stretto rispetto alla risposta di abarisone, potrebbe anche significare semplicemente la manutenzione del palazzo in cui il priorato ha sede. Spesso la parola "priorato" è usata sia per indicare l'istituzione e sia per indicare il [palazzo](https://arttrip.it/visitare-il-priorato-di-malta-sull-aventino/) stesso.

Comment: +1 Onestamente questa è la prima interpretazione che mi è saltata alla mente, l'unico problema è che il paese qui sembra troppo piccolo per avere qualcosa di più di una piccola canonica

Comment: Sì, giusta osservazione

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Probabilmente quello che sto per dire non ha nessun senso ma, pensando a Firenze mi è venuto in mente che l'attuale sede del Comune, cioè Palazzo Vecchio, era in origine il palazzo dei priori delle arti (lo stesso Dante fu uno di questi priori). Quindi potrebbe trattarsi del Comune.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ho appena trovato un'altra interpretazione sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, dove si trova appunto la citazione riportata nella domanda.